# broadleaf commerce demo site issue

Tags: spring, maven, solr, broadleaf-commerce

I currently started using broadleaf commerce framework. I downloaded the **demo site** from their site which includes 4 folders (site, admin, api, core). then I successfully ran the **mvn install** command. when I wanted to run **mvn spring-boot:run** the following error occured:

```
2018-05-27 13:59:26.784  INFO 13536 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-05-27 13:59:26.797 ERROR 13536 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException: Failed to invoke event listener method
HandlerMethod details: 
Bean [com.community.core.service.search.SolrIndexCleanupServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c6631d93]
Method [public void com.community.core.service.search.SolrIndexCleanupServiceImpl.rebuildIndexAtStartupIfNecessary() throws org.broadleafcommerce.common.exception.ServiceException,java.io.IOException]
Resolved arguments: 

    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:273) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:177) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:140) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:393) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:883) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at com.community.admin.AdminApplication.main(AdminApplication.java:18) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.broadleafcommerce.common.exception.ServiceException: Could not delete documents
    at org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.index.SolrIndexServiceImpl.deleteAllNamespaceDocuments(SolrIndexServiceImpl.java:339) ~[broadleaf-framework-5.2.3-GA.jar:na]
    at org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.index.SolrIndexServiceImpl.preBuildIndex(SolrIndexServiceImpl.java:183) ~[broadleaf-framework-5.2.3-GA.jar:na]
    at org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.index.SolrIndexServiceImpl.rebuildIndex(SolrIndexServiceImpl.java:174) ~[broadleaf-framework-5.2.3-GA.jar:na]
    at com.community.core.service.search.SolrIndexCleanupServiceImpl.rebuildIndexAtStartupIfNecessary(SolrIndexCleanupServiceImpl.java:54) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.community.core.service.search.SolrIndexCleanupServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b84b8451.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738) ~[spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673) ~[spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at com.community.core.service.search.SolrIndexCleanupServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c6631d93.rebuildIndexAtStartupIfNecessary(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:256) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: Server refused connection at: http://localhost:8983/solr/catalog_reindex
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:567) ~[solr-solrj-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:48:17]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:234) ~[solr-solrj-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:48:17]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:226) ~[solr-solrj-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:48:17]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:135) ~[solr-solrj-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:48:17]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.deleteByQuery(SolrClient.java:896) ~[solr-solrj-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:48:17]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.deleteByQuery(SolrClient.java:859) ~[solr-solrj-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:48:17]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.deleteByQuery(SolrClient.java:874) ~[solr-solrj-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:48:17]
    at org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.index.SolrIndexServiceImpl.deleteAllNamespaceDocuments(SolrIndexServiceImpl.java:331) ~[broadleaf-framework-5.2.3-GA.jar:na]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:326) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.5.jar:4.5.5]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:465) ~[solr-solrj-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:48:17]
    ... 42 common frames omitted

2018-05-27 13:59:26.799  INFO 13536 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3ba9ad43: startup date [Sun May 27 13:58:55 IRDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-05-27 13:59:26.805  INFO 13536 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 0
2018-05-27 13:59:26.806  INFO 13536 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase -2147483648
2018-05-27 13:59:26.909  INFO 13536 --- [           main] c.b.autoconfigure.HSQLDBServer           : Stopping HSQL server...
[Server@7f1f7edd]: Initiating shutdown sequence...
[Server@7f1f7edd]: Shutdown sequence completed in 132 ms.
[Server@7f1f7edd]: 2018-05-27 13:59:27.042 SHUTDOWN : System.exit() was not called
2018-05-27 13:59:27.050  INFO 13536 --- [           main] o.s.jmx.export.MBeanExporter             : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2018-05-27 13:59:27.051  INFO 13536 --- [           main] o.s.jmx.export.MBeanExporter             : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
2018-05-27 13:59:27.092  INFO 13536 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'blPU'
2018-05-27 13:59:27.092  INFO 13536 --- [           main] o.b.c.c.e.AbstractHydratedCacheManager   : Disposing of all hydrated cache members
2018-05-27 13:59:27.098  INFO 13536 --- [           main] o.b.c.c.e.AbstractHydratedCacheManager   : Disposing of all hydrated cache members
2018-05-27 13:59:27.150  INFO 13536 --- [           main] o.b.c.c.e.AbstractHydratedCacheManager   : Disposing of all hydrated cache members
2018-05-27 13:59:27.153  INFO 13536 --- [           main] o.b.c.c.e.AbstractHydratedCacheManager   : Disposing of all hydrated cache members
2018-05-27 13:59:27.163  INFO 13536 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'blCMSStorage'
2018-05-27 13:59:27.163  INFO 13536 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'blSecurePU'
2018-05-27 13:59:27.164  INFO 13536 --- [           main] o.s.jmx.export.MBeanExporter             : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2018-05-27 13:59:27.164  INFO 13536 --- [           main] o.s.jmx.export.MBeanExporter             : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
2018-05-27 13:59:27.174  INFO 13536 --- [           main] b.c.e.c.e.MergeEhCacheManagerFactoryBean : Shutting down EhCache CacheManager
```

I carefully read this error and spent lots of hours and finally I found that this is related to solar search engine. I decided to run solar locally. I downloaded solar search engine and configured it according to the instructions given in [this link](https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/broadleaf-concepts/catalog-and-search/deployment-models/stand-alone/solr-stand-alone-index) but unfortunately I did not find solrconfig.xml and schema.xml in the version that I downloaded, so I searched on net and found other files. I re-ran the admin area but I got the follosing error:

```
2018-05-27 14:23:28.980  INFO 8264 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-05-27 14:23:28.990 ERROR 8264 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException: Failed to invoke event listener method
HandlerMethod details: 
Bean [com.community.core.service.search.SolrIndexCleanupServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fa6b7973]
Method [public void com.community.core.service.search.SolrIndexCleanupServiceImpl.rebuildIndexAtStartupIfNecessary() throws org.broadleafcommerce.common.exception.ServiceException,java.io.IOException]
Resolved arguments: 

    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:273) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:177) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:140) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:393) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:883) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
    at com.community.admin.AdminApplication.main(AdminApplication.java:18) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.broadleafcommerce.common.exception.ServiceException: Could not delete documents
    at org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.index.SolrIndexServiceImpl.deleteAllNamespaceDocuments(SolrIndexServiceImpl.java:339) ~[broadleaf-framework-5.2.3-GA.jar:na]
    at org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.index.SolrIndexServiceImpl.preBuildIndex(SolrIndexServiceImpl.java:183) ~[broadleaf-framework-5.2.3-GA.jar:na]
    at org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.index.SolrIndexServiceImpl.rebuildIndex(SolrIndexServiceImpl.java:174) ~[broadleaf-framework-5.2.3-GA.jar:na]
    at com.community.core.service.search.SolrIndexCleanupServiceImpl.rebuildIndexAtStartupIfNecessary(SolrIndexCleanupServiceImpl.java:54) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.community.core.service.search.SolrIndexCleanupServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b84b8451.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738) ~[spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673) ~[spring-aop-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    at com.community.core.service.search.SolrIndexCleanupServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fa6b7973.rebuildIndexAtStartupIfNecessary(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:256) ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/catalog_reindex: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/catalog_reindex/update. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p><hr><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><hr/>

</body>
</html>

    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:528) ~[solr-solrj-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:48:17]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:234) ~[solr-solrj-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:48:17]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:226) ~[solr-solrj-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:48:17]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:135) ~[solr-solrj-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:48:17]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.deleteByQuery(SolrClient.java:896) ~[solr-solrj-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:48:17]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.deleteByQuery(SolrClient.java:859) ~[solr-solrj-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:48:17]
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.deleteByQuery(SolrClient.java:874) ~[solr-solrj-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1 1703449 - noble - 2015-09-17 01:48:17]
    at org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.index.SolrIndexServiceImpl.deleteAllNamespaceDocuments(SolrIndexServiceImpl.java:331) ~[broadleaf-framework-5.2.3-GA.jar:na]
    ... 35 common frames omitted

2018-05-27 14:23:28.992  INFO 8264 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@3ba9ad43: startup date [Sun May 27 14:22:58 IRDT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-05-27 14:23:28.998  INFO 8264 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 0
2018-05-27 14:23:28.999  INFO 8264 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase -2147483648
2018-05-27 14:23:29.100  INFO 8264 --- [           main] c.b.autoconfigure.HSQLDBServer           : Stopping HSQL server...
[Server@3e073950]: Initiating shutdown sequence...
[Server@3e073950]: Shutdown sequence completed in 112 ms.
[Server@3e073950]: 2018-05-27 14:23:29.213 SHUTDOWN : System.exit() was not called
2018-05-27 14:23:29.225  INFO 8264 --- [           main] o.s.jmx.export.MBeanExporter             : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2018-05-27 14:23:29.225  INFO 8264 --- [           main] o.s.jmx.export.MBeanExporter             : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
2018-05-27 14:23:29.268  INFO 8264 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'blPU'
2018-05-27 14:23:29.269  INFO 8264 --- [           main] o.b.c.c.e.AbstractHydratedCacheManager   : Disposing of all hydrated cache members
2018-05-27 14:23:29.274  INFO 8264 --- [           main] o.b.c.c.e.AbstractHydratedCacheManager   : Disposing of all hydrated cache members
2018-05-27 14:23:29.280  INFO 8264 --- [           main] o.b.c.c.e.AbstractHydratedCacheManager   : Disposing of all hydrated cache members
2018-05-27 14:23:29.284  INFO 8264 --- [           main] o.b.c.c.e.AbstractHydratedCacheManager   : Disposing of all hydrated cache members
2018-05-27 14:23:29.294  INFO 8264 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'blCMSStorage'
2018-05-27 14:23:29.294  INFO 8264 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'blSecurePU'
2018-05-27 14:23:29.295  INFO 8264 --- [           main] o.s.jmx.export.MBeanExporter             : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2018-05-27 14:23:29.295  INFO 8264 --- [           main] o.s.jmx.export.MBeanExporter             : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
2018-05-27 14:23:29.309  INFO 8264 --- [           main] b.c.e.c.e.MergeEhCacheManagerFactoryBean : Shutting down EhCache CacheManager
```

I have no idea what to do next. I would be glad if you help me solve the issue.

Comment: Can you post the entire startup log? There should be something there about Solr, specifically that it is trying to download Solr (this should happen automatically). Can you also check if you have anything running on port 8983?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I installed Solr and made some examples to see if Solr runs on my environment and everything seems to be ok but still i can not install Broadleaf locally. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue that gave the same error. Upon inspecting the log file (/tmp/solr-/solr-/server/logs/solr.log on my linux box) I found that it couldn't start the jvm. When I downgraded to open-jdk-1.8 installed via yum (I had manually installed open-jdk-11 before), solr was able to start properly.

So I'd make sure you're using a supported java version and that it is installed in a way that solr expects (e.g. JAVA_HOME is set).

Answer (score 0):

Set JAVA_HOME environment variable to version 1.8

[image]

Then restart your machine.